# How to change Forms 2.0 BorderStyle with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to show/hide the border of "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Label" I use in Excel.

I can manually change the borderstyle from `0 - fmBorderStyleNone` to `1 - fmBorderStyleSingle`. What I would have liked is to span from 10 to 20 form 2.0 Shapes. So this makes no fun.

It should go, if this is right … [like this](https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=126:excel-userform-and-controls-properties-setting-control-properties-at-design-time-or-run-time&catid=79)

```
For Each sh In .Shapes
    .Select         ' just for debugging
    Select Case sh.Type
        Case 12     ' 2.0 Forms Label
            sh.BorderStyle = 0
    End Select
Next sh
```

How to change Forms 2.0 BorderStyle with VBA?

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)
• What is your actual question and issue? Which errors do you get and where? What does your code do vs. what did you expect it to do. Reading [ask] might also help to improve your question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
If i run this Code, i'll get
"runtime error 438 object doesn't support this property or method" back.
What do i have to Change?

Comment: In which line of your code do you get the error? And are your labels on a worksheet or on a userform?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
For Each sh In .Shapes
    .Select         ' just for debugging
    Select Case sh.Type
        Case 12     ' 2.0 Forms Label
            sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object.BorderStyle = 0
    End Select
Next sh
```